# How can I conditionally display an image based on a tag's value in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am very new to React and I've been reading the documentation on conditionals, but I can't seem to make things work here.

[Edited to reflect suggestions in comments]

I have this:

```
function MyGraphOne(props){return <img src='/graphOne.png' />;}
function MyGraphThree(props){return <img src='/graphThree.png' />;}
```

I have a value called {pattern} that can be one of three values: one, two, or three.

I thought it would be as simple as writing something like this:

```
function displayMyGraph(props){
    if (props.pattern == 'one'){ //or 'two', or 'three'
       return <MyGraphOne />
    }
    return <MyGraphThree />
}
```

The function is returning MyGraphThree regardless of the pattern value.

Comment: You may have a typo in your code, a condition should be `==` or `===` not `=`, otherwise this is an assignation.

Comment: you need to return something by default. (it is ok to return `null` in react)

Comment: React component names should start with capital letter so it should be `MyGraphOne`

Comment: Welp... that was it. I can't believe I still make that mistake.

Comment: Ok -- it's 'working' but incorrectly. If the pattern value is 'one' is displays the default graph; in this case, the graph that it should display for 'three'. Edited code to reflect.

Comment: Fixed. Using pattern, not props.pattern